# How can I break out of double quotes for XSS?

Tags: javascript, xss, penetration-testing

The following is a piece of code that I have for testing. I'm trying to escape out and add a DOM based XSS attack to it, but am unable to get a payload alert(1) to activate. I have tried multiple variations of escaping with double quotes see below. Is there a way to break out of the double quotes in the given function?

```
&quot&ltimg src='x' onerror='alert(1)'&gt&quot(
\&lt/p&gt&ltimg src='x' onerror='alert(1)'&gt&quot\(\
    

<script>

        var h = document.location.hash.substring(1);
        if (h && h != "") {
            var re = new RegExp(".+@.+");
            if (h.match(re)) {
                document.getElementById("email").innerHTML += " ("+h+")";
            }
        }

        </script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'break out of the double quotes' exactly?

Comment: A simple `...#<script>alert(1)</script>@foo` should work for this. If it gets encoded like in the first line of your snippet, the application is not vulnerable, the problem is not a double quote (there is no double quote to break out from).

Answer (score 0):

@gabor-lengyel explained in the comments that the code essentially is working as expected: if the XSS line gets encoded then it isn't exposing a vulnerability in the application so there isn't a double quote in the first place.